# Dependency injection in .NET: how to get services in classes not created by the DI service container?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dependency-injection

How can I get services from a DI service container in classes that don't get instantiated by the container itself and for which thus I cannot simply declare constructors with appropriate parameters for the services I need to get? Do I need to pass a reference to the container from class to class till I reach the class where I need to retrieve those services from the container or is there a smarter way to retrieve a reference to the container from anywhere in my application code?

Below adding some details to my initial question.

It seems to me that sometimes it's simply not worth it to register all classes with the DI container and still you might need to retrieve services from the DI container in some classes. I was then wondering if there is a best practice to get a reference to the DI container other than passing this reference around from class to class via parameters in methods.

In a large or complex application how do you achieve easy access from any class to the DI container to get the services you need?

Comment: Why would you do this? Why don't you use DI? Can you provide a more specific example?

Answer (score 3):

What you're enquiring about sounds like the Service Locator Pattern which is usually considered an anti pattern.

Without knowing the reason *why* you think you're unable to use any "normal" DI approach, it's difficult to ensure that giving an answer on how to do it is really the best way to go.

But if you insist, then one way to achieve it is to "build" the service provider in the startup (after you're finished adding services to the service collection) and then to put that object into a statically accessible location.

E.g.

`MyServiceLocator.Instance = services.BuildServiceProvider();`

Then from your target class you can refer to it, e.g.
`MyServiceLocator.Instance.GetRequiredService<T>();`

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the class has some parameters that can't be registered in DI container (for example they vary per instance creation for some reason). You can use factory approach here. For example by registering factory via `Func`:

```cs
services.AddScoped<Func<string, MyNonDiClass>>(serviceProvider =>
    s => new MyNonDiClass(serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<SomeDiParam>(), s));

class MyNonDiClass
{
    public MyNonDiClass(SomeDiParam p1, string nonDi)
    {
        // ..
    }
}
```

Or basically the same but with dedicated class which will have `CreateMyNonDiClass` method.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can inject the IoC container as a dependency but it is generally considered an anti-pattern.

```cs
public class MyFunkyClass
{
  public MyFunkyClass(IServiceProvider serviceLocator)
  {
    var dependency = serviceLocator.GetRequiredService<T>();
  }
}
```